# Как в нейронную сеть засунуть данные из CSV файла?

Tags: python, dataframe, big-data

Как в нейронную сеть засунуть данные из CSV файла?

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос конечно нужно конкретизировать! Но в самом простом случае - представим, что в CSV файле исключительно числовые данные (никаких строк, никаких дат и времени и т.д.), т.к. большинство моделей нейронных сетей умеют работать только с числовыми данными. Еще договоримся, что метки (результат для обучающего набора данных), находятся в отдельном CSV файле.

```
import pandas as pd

filename_X_train = r"/path/to/train_X.csv"
filename_Y_train = r"/path/to/train_Y.csv"

X_train = pd.read_csv(filename_X_train, sep=",")
Y_train = pd.read_csv(filename_Y_train, sep=",")


#model = <...> # здесь вы строите и компилируете свою НС модель

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, ...)  # вместо троеточия подставляете необходимые параметры 
для обучения модели
```